# Apt-get crashes with : relocation error: libapt-pkg.so.4.12

Tags: apt

After running a simple upgrade I get a crash each time I try to use `apt-get`. Any command crashes with the same error message :

```
legaliz_me:~$ sudo apt-get
apt-get: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.4.12: symbol DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF_ZNSt6vectorIN3APT13Configuration10CompressorESaIS2_EE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS2_S4_EERKS2_, version GLIBCXX_3.4 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
```

Full log : http://pastebin.com/BmTE5erZ

I don't remember adding any crazy edger ppa or anything special with my system. I'm running 14.04 64bits. Is apt broken for any other person?

Comment: [PLEASE ADD TO COMMENT I JUST NEED CLARIFICATION] Did you recently add any different libraries 32/64 bit? I am not sure if this answer will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386651/how-to-fix-usr-lib-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found

Comment: The images are not stable yet, wait for the final release.

Answer (score 2):

I had some corrupted dependency which may have prevented libc6 from updating. I checked the package version using :

```
$ dpkg -l apt libc6  libapt-pkg4.12:amd64
  libapt-pkg4.12:amd64       1.0.1ubuntu2 
  libc6:amd64                2.19-0ubuntu6
  libc6:i386                 2.19-0ubuntu6
```

I checked md5 of those packages and found that `libapt-pkg4.12:amd64` was corrupted by comparing with another user.

```
$ md5sum /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.4.12
```

Fixed it by manually installing `libc6` and `libapt-pkg4.12` from launchpad .deb packages : [libapt-pkg4.12](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/libapt-pkg4.12), [libc6](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/libc6)

```
sudo dpkg -i libc6_2.19-0ubuntu6_i386.deb libc6_2.19-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb libapt-pkg4.12_1.0.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

After I forced the update so the old dependencies got updated

```
sudo apt-get -f upgrade
```

And now everything's fine.

Comment: To people with similar issues: just to be safe in case the `apt` package itself is corrupt, you should also download and install the [current `apt_*.deb`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt) for your release. In fact, re-install all binary packages built from the `apt` source package, that are currently installed on your system.